# Resize Textbox based on the type of browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I got a textbox in my form that i want to resize its width depending on the type of browser that I'm using for example firefox.I got a JQuery code that detects which browser I'm using, and CSS to reduce the width of the textbox, but how can i use this together to do what i want or is there a easier way to resize the textbox depending on the browser?

**JQuery**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script> 
// Opera 8.0+
var isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;

// Firefox 1.0+
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

// Safari 3.0+ "[object HTMLElementConstructor]" 
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0 || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || safari.pushNotification);

// Internet Explorer 6-11
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;

// Edge 20+
var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;

// Chrome 1+
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;

// Blink engine detection
var isBlink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;

jQuery(function($) 
{                        
    if(isChrome) {
        console.log("Using Chrome");
    }

    else if(isFirefox) {
        //$("#DOB").mask("99/99/9999",{placeholder:" "});
        console.log("Using FireFox");
    }               
});    
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
#DOB
{
width:100%;
max-width: 172px    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add classes to your body tag based on the browser, and style based on them. For example:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) 
{                        
    if (isChrome) {
        $('body').addClass('browser-chrome');
    } else if(isFirefox) {
        $('body').addClass('browser-firefox');
    }               
});    
</script>

<style>
.browser-chrome #DOB {
    width: 100%;   
}

.browser-firefox #DOB {
    width: 80%;   
}
</style>
```